# I am getting data from json web services but unable to display it on my ui

Tags: ios, json, swift3

here I am having problem that I am able to get the data from json web services but unable to display on my ui in the program I mentioned where I am getting error and what it is also mentioned there can anyone help me ?

```
class DetailsViewController: UIPageViewController{

    @IBOutlet var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textview: UITextView!

    var productName :String?
    var productprice :String?
    var productdescription :String?
    var thumbnailimageArray = [String]()
    var imageArray = [String]()
    var pageIndex: Int = 0


let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cjpberBhKa?indent=2"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.downloadJsonWithURL()
        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft) //unexpectely found nil while unwrapping an optional value
        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count
        pageControl.currentPage = pageIndex
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail")!)
                if let detailsArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail") as? NSArray {
                    if let detailDict = detailsArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = detailDict.value(forKey: "productName") {
                            self.productName = name as? String
                        }
                        if let image1 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image1"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image1 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image2 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image2"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image2 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image3 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image3"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image3 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image4 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image4"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image4 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image5 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image5"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image5 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image6 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image6"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image6 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image7 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image7"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image7 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image8 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image8"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image8 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image9 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image9"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image9 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image10 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image10"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image10 as! String)
                        }
                        if let price = detailDict.value(forKey: "productPrice") {
                            self.productprice = price as? String
                        }
                        if let description = detailDict.value(forKey: "productDes") {
                            self.productdescription = description as? String
                        }
                    }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.navigationBar.topItem?.title = self.productName
                    self.textview.text = self.productdescription
                    self.priceLabel.text = self.productprice
                    print(self.imageArray)
                    let imgURL = NSURL(string:self.imageArray[0])
                    let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right :
                if pageIndex == 0 {

                }else{
                    pageIndex -= 1
                }
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[pageIndex])
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
                if pageIndex >= imageArray.count-1{

                }else{
                    pageIndex += 1
                }
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[pageIndex])
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats the error??

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)` nad check if imageView is nil. If that is the case connect the outlet properly.

Comment: @bilal  self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)  here I am getting error i.e. unexpectely found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Comment: Crash happen when you swipe??

Comment: no second view controller has not loaded @bilal

Comment: after coming to that line the program stops showing mentioned error

Comment: @Rishab is right... `self.imageView` is nil. Go to Your storyboard and check the imageView is connected properly. And there is another problem with your code, you are not passing the gesture selectors correctly.

Comment: I don't have any outlet connection problem I checked twice and not problem with passing the gestures also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are using to display image in `func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)` method execution is as below

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[pageIndex])
```

but your image is comping from the server so you just need to display all images of your product is as you displayed first in `OperationQueue.main.addOperation` so in place of displaying image using `UIImage(named: imageArray[pageIndex])` you need to convert it to data and display it to imageview and your modified `func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)` may look like as below

```
func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right :
                if pageIndex == 0 {

                }else{
                    pageIndex -= 1
                }
                let imgURL = NSURL(string:self.imageArray[pageIndex])
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
                if pageIndex >= imageArray.count-1{

                }else{
                    pageIndex += 1
                }
                let imgURL = NSURL(string:self.imageArray[pageIndex])
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```