# I had tried displaying collection view on the ui but unable to display can anyone help me?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

here I tried to implement the collection view but unable to do it and on scroll view I had placed the collection view is it correct to implement like this if not can u provide any solution for this to display on ui and 
in this scroll view has implemented on view and all the elements are placed on it here is my code and how to zoom a selected particular image also can anyone help me ?

```
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textview: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var productName = [String]()
    var productprice = [String]()
    var productdescription :String?
    var thumbnailimageArray = [String]()
    var imageArray = [String]()
    var pageIndex: Int = 0
    var imagesArray = [String]()

let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cjpberBhKa?indent=2"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.downloadJsonWithURL()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped(gesture:)))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
        swipeLeft.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped(gesture:)))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
        swipeRight.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail")!)
                if let detailsArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail") as? NSArray {
                    if let detailDict = detailsArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = detailDict.value(forKey: "productName") {
                            self.productName.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let image1 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image1"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image1 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image2 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image2"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image2 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image3 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image3"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image3 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image4 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image4"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image4 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image5 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image5"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image5 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image6 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image6"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image6 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image7 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image7"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image7 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image8 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image8"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image8 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image9 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image9"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image9 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image10 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image10"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image10 as! String)
                        }
                        if let price = detailDict.value(forKey: "productPrice") {
                            self.productprice.append(price as! String)
                        }
                        if let description = detailDict.value(forKey: "productDes") {
                            self.productdescription = description as? String
                        }
                        if let image = detailDict.value(forKey: "img"){
                            self.imagesArray.append(image as! String)
                        }
                    }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.navigationBar.topItem?.title = self.productName[0]
                    self.textview.text = self.productdescription
                    self.priceLabel.text = self.productprice[0]
                    self.nameLabel.text = self.productName[0]
                    print(self.imageArray)
                    let imgURL = NSURL(string:self.imageArray[0])
                    let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right :
                if pageIndex == 0 {

                }else{
                    pageIndex -= 1
                }
                let imgURL = NSURL(string:self.imageArray[pageIndex])
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count
                pageControl.currentPage = pageIndex
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
                if pageIndex >= imageArray.count-1{

                }else{
                    pageIndex += 1
                }
                let imgURL = NSURL(string:self.imageArray[pageIndex])
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count
                pageControl.currentPage = pageIndex
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagesArray.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell",for:indexPath) as! DetailsCell
        let arr = imagesArray[indexPath.row]
        let urls = NSURL(string: arr)
        let data = NSData (contentsOf: urls! as URL)
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
        cell.nameLabel.text = self.productName[indexPath.row]
        cell.priceLabel.text = self.productprice[indexPath.row]
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.7
     return cell
    }
```

Comment: You posted a question a while ago with the same code and even accepted an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082366/i-am-getting-data-from-json-web-services-but-unable-to-display-it-on-my-ui  Are you looking for answers??

Comment: @Vamsi What is the display by you now ? You can provide an image.

Comment: @bilal I tried to implement the image view in same task but not able to display on it that's reason I posted

Comment: I phone 7 display size I tried display the image but unable to post

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWYQr.png this is the image link @aircraft

Comment: @Vamsi Do you mean you want to create a banner which display several image view, and when a imageView of them displaying, it will become more bigger?

Comment: I am having set of images also that to display on image view and if I select a particular image then it should zoom

Comment: @Vamsi Zoom like what? zoom a little bigger? or pop out to another ViewController or a view?

Comment: pop out to another view controller and zoom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reload your `collection view` after you fetch all the `data` from the `web service response` like below.

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: it was working when only collection view on the ui but I am having the page like this where it doesn't works  
i.stack.imgur.com/QWYQr.png

Comment: I didn't get what you said.  `it was working when only collection view on the ui`. so where is you collection view

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/QWYQr.png you just check the image here I am presenting the collection view below the description

Answer (score 0):

You need reload data of collectionview after downloadJsonWithURL loaded.

Comment: how to reload the collection view and what is the code for that  ?

Comment: `func downloadJsonWithURL() {   
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)  
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {  
                // your code  
            }  

            DispatchQueue.main.async {  

                // Update your UI here  
                // Reload collectionView data here  
                collectionView.reloadData()  
            }
        }).resume()  
    }`